# How to use VSCode CLI to open the `hosts` file on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, visual-studio-code, git-bash, hosts

Tried `code '%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'` using Git Bash, but it fails to resolve `%SystemRoot%`, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: bash doesn't use `%variablename%` for environment variable references. IIRC you would need to write `$SystemRoot` rather than `%SystemRoot%`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Thanks, it's actually `$SYSTEMROOT`.

Comment: In that case bash is changing it to uppercase (Windows uses mixed case for the environment variable name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do with VSCode CLI, but you can try using `WINDIR` environment variable, e.g. in [MinGW](http://mingw.osdn.io/index.html) (which is what Git Bash based on):

```sh
$ echo "$WINDIR/system32/drivers/etc/hosts"
C:\WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

Note that forward and backslashes are interchangeable in file names in Windows & MinGW-based tools.

Comment: Thanks, where's `$WINDIR` documented?

Comment: I've been using this: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html . I'm not aware of an official spec from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, that's very informative, excerpt from there: _%windir% is a regular User variable and can be changed, which makes it less robust than %SystemRoot%_, I guess `$SYSTEMROOT` is better in this case?

Comment: $WINDIR can be changed by the user, $SYSTEMROOT can't (apparently). So I guess $SYSTEMROOT is better.